# Links to magentocommerce.com are really annoying, can we do a mass delete?

Tags: discussion

Lots of times when I browse either the magento tag on stack or magento.se I see links in the answers to http://www.magentocommerce.com/ and I get redirected to homepage.

I don't know what was that website or what happened to it because I'm quite new to magento, but it is really annoying and it takes forever to load and in the end it gives you nothing.

I got fooled so many times that normally I wouldn't ever click on a link to magentocommerce.com but most of the time it is not obvious that they go to that site as it is just an anchor on some text.

So, given that all (or almost all?) of those links are broken, can we just delete them because it is just noise and a time waste.

Answer (score 6):

Most of those links point to the old forum or the old wiki, both have been shut down this year.

The content of the forum is gone forever, except that you might find it on the archive.org wayback machine. The wiki has been replaced with the merchant docs at http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html and the dev docs at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ where you find most of the topics, but as far as I can see there is no 1:1 transfer.

What I would do with those links is, check if the content is available elsewhere, change the link and cite the important parts to keep the answer valuable without the link (if it wasn't already just given as source). **Unfortunately this is nothing that you can do automatically.**

Deleting answers with dead links is not an option, except if they are "link only" answers that have no value at all without the link (and those should be deleted or improved anyway)

Comment: I'd close the old forums too with all the update chaos from the old days.